# Is there a way to go back to TRY block after error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, exception

I want to check in my stored procedure, if a table contains specific columns. I want to raise an error if such a column exist, because they are not allowed. First I came up with the following idea, which obviously has a defect that I can understand.

```
  BEGIN TRY 

  SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 0 forbidden_column_name1 INTO #t1 FROM ' + @input_table ;
  EXEC @err = sp_executesql @sql ;
  IF @err = 0  -- i.e. if succeeds
    RAISERROR('Input table cannot contain ''forbidden_column_name1''. This name is reserved!', 16, 99) ;

  SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 0 forbidden_column_name2 INTO #t1 FROM ' + @input_table ;
  EXEC @err = sp_executesql @sql ;
  IF @err = 0  -- i.e. if succeeds
    RAISERROR('Input table cannot contain ''forbidden_column_name2''. This name is reserved!', 16, 99) ;

  SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 0 forbidden_column_name3 INTO #t1 FROM ' + @input_table ;
  EXEC @err = sp_executesql @sql ;
  IF @err = 0  -- i.e. if succeeds
    RAISERROR('Input table cannot contain ''forbidden_column_name3''. This name is reserved!', 16, 99) ;

  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_STATE() = 99
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
      DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
      DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

      SELECT 
          @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
          @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
          @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

      RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
      RETURN ;
    END
    -- Do nothing and continue execution, if column doesn't exist
  END CATCH
```

This code would check only the existence of `forbidden_column_name1`. The others are not checked, because an exception has to be raised during the check of `forbidden_column_name1`: either from the `sp_executesql`, if column doesn't exist, or from the `RAISERROR`, if the column *does* exist. Either way, the execution passes to catch block and never comes back.

My question is, is there a way to force the execution go back to the TRY block, if an error is not actually an *error*, but actually something that is desired. Otherwise I have to put all checks in separate TRY/CATCH blocks, which makes the code seem a little bit redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to wrap each individual select statement in a try/catch block.

```
BEGIN TRY 

    SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 0 forbidden_column_name1 INTO #t1 FROM ' + @input_table ;
    EXEC @err = sp_executesql @sql ;
    IF @err = 0  -- i.e. if succeeds
        RAISERROR('Input table cannot contain ''forbidden_column_name1''. This name is reserved!', 16, 99) ;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_STATE() = 99
        EXEC usp_RethrowError
END CATCH
```

To avoid repeating yourself, you could create a procedure for this that has parameters for both the name of the table, and the name of the column.

[Definition of usp_RethrowError](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/roman_rehak/archive/2007/12/01/how-to-rethrow-errors-in-t-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Why not query [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), to determine the existence or not of these columns, rather than trying to infer their existence by querying the table?

---

e.g.

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name) and name in (
    'forbidden_column1','forbidden_column2','forbidden_column3'))
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('One or more forbidden columns detected. Review the documentation',16,99)
    RETURN
END

--Proceed, knowing that the table doesn't contain the forbidden columns
```

Comment: `@input_table` is a fully qualified tablename, like `mydb.myschema.mytable`. I don't know `sys.columns` of which database I am supposed to query. I need to extract the database name and query the sys.columns with dynamic SQL. A viable option, of course. So do you think the answer to my question definitely NO?

Comment: Going across databases does make it a bit trickier, agreed. But there's no facility to "resume" into a try block from a catch block (I think there are some languages with such constructs, T-SQL isn't one of them)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but you're better off using INFORMATION_SCHEMA to determine if the columns exist.

Something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = @input_table AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('forbidden_column_name1', 'forbidden_column_name2', 'etc'))
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('idiot', 16, 99)
END
```

Comment: If it's not an answer to the question why post it as an answer then? Should be a comment. In any event this is subjective. I prefer `IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','column_name') IS NULL`. Not portable but neither is `RAISERROR`

Comment: It doesn't answer his _question_ but it answers his _problem_ as stated in the question.  I would have put it in a comment but the code isn't as readable in the comments section.

Comment: I've retracted my downvote as it was probably just a knee jerk response to the first 6 words of your answer. Still don't see that this adds anything over and above the other answer. Why would `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` be any better than `sys.columns`? It is still database scoped.

Comment: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views follow the ISO standard for them and using them will enable [applications to work correctly although significant changes have been made to the underlying system tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).

Comment: Bit of a non issue in my experience. Microsoft still support `syscolumns` etc. as backward compatibility views. Note that link you give has a big warning text "Some changes have been made to the information schema views that break backward compatibility." which somewhat contradicts the point you are attempting to make.

Comment: I think the issue that Steve points out here is not backwards compatibility, but rather compatibility across different database environments.

Comment: @ercan - What's the point? The whole script in the OP is riddled with proprietary syntax.